# How do I get dojo.currency.format to use the correct currency symbol when using a custom dojo build?

Tags: dojo, formatting, currency

When I use my custom build of dojo, dojo.currency.format doesn't use the correct currency symbol.

This is the statement I use:

```
dojo.currency.format(1234.567, {currency: "USD"});
```

This is the result when I use the standard dojo release:

```
"$1,234.57"
```

This is the result when I use my custom build of dojo:

```
"¤1,234.57"
```

How can I get my custom dojo build to produce the correct results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue when first trying to use the dojo build.  It has to do with the character encoding of the files.  Check out the character encoding of an unzipped release (non source).  Compare that to the character encoding of files in unbuilt source, and the encoding of files are a custom build.  To see if this is an issue, (in chrome) you can force the browser to render the contents in a given encoding.  You can try this to see if it is actually the issue you are having.

The easy solution to this (for me at least) was to set the `charset` on the dojo script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/dojo" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Dojo has a [couple](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/internationalization/globalization-guidelines/encoding-guidelines.html) of [pages](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/internationalization/encoding-considerations.html) on encoding that are worth taking a look at.

If you are using [shrinksafe in the build](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/shrinksafe/), you may also need to specify the encoding there:

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 shrinksafe.jar
```

Comment: How do I check out the character encoding?

Comment: Adding the charset attribute to the script tag of the layer that contains dojo.currency solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: like I said,  that is how solved it, it doesn't necessarily seem like the 'correct' fix though.. It might be worth following up on the mailing list for the definitive/correct answer.

Comment: I had huge problems with this and found I had to add charset="UTF-8" to the script tag for my custom layer, as well as dojo.js.  Just putting charset="UTF-8" on dojo.js meant my dojo.currency.format and dijit.form.CurrencyTextBox would output the universal currency symbol.  Also, beware the browser cache.. I found I had to manually clear the Chrome cache (shift-ctrl-delete and 'Empty the cache') to make it re-load the .js resource with the new encoding, otherwise it would use the old version despite me having changed the charset specified on the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does your build have access to dojo/cldr/nls directory for the localization files of your locale? Check in Firebug whether it attempts, but fails to load currency.js from mentioned directory.